# Libreria calendar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hola buenas tardes estoy usando la libreria Calendar de flutter  hace varios dias vengo intentando mostrar los turnos y con los respectivos pacientes que tengo en la base de datos, Toda la informacion que necesito mostrar esta en
**turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId** pero no se como hacerlo en la libreria, agradezco si me podrian explicar/ayudar porque estoy muy atascado con esto. Estuve siguiendo un tutorial en youtube, pero mi drama es que no se como entrelazar la variable con las propiedades de la libreria, ya intente de todo lo que tengo para hacer que funcione :C

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  CalendarController _controller;
  String dni;
  List<PatientModels> patientModels = new List();
  TurnModel turnModel = new TurnModel();
  List turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId = new List();
  UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
  List<EmployeeModel> employeModel = new List();
  Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> _events;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = CalendarController();
    _events = {};
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = Provider.of(context);
    userModel = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Usuario: ${bloc.userName} home page'),
          centerTitle: true),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            TableCalendar(
              locale: 'en_US',
              events: _events,
              calendarController: _controller,
              calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(todayColor: Colors.deepPurple),
              onDaySelected: (day, events) {},
            ),
            // ...turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId.map(
            //   (e) => ListTile(
            //     title: Text(
            //       'Nombre: ${patientModels[0].firstName} - ${patientModels[0].lastName}',
            //     ),
            //   ),
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => {
          buscarMedico(context),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  //se busca el paciente por dni
  buscarPaciente(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Buscar Paciente'),
          content: TextFormField(
            focusNode: FocusNode(canRequestFocus: true),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            onChanged: (value) {
              dni = value;
            },
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop('OK');
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop('Cancel');
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ).then((value) => {
          if (value == 'OK') {submitPaciente(context)}
        });
  }
//se busca el medico por dni 
  buscarMedico(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Buscar Medico'),
          content: TextFormField(
            focusNode: FocusNode(canRequestFocus: true),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            onChanged: (value) {
              dni = value;
            },
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop('OK');
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop('Cancel');
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ).then((value) => {
          if (value == 'OK') {submitMedico(context)}
        });
  }

  //se hace la peticion a la api del medico
  void submitMedico(BuildContext context) async {
    employeModel = await employeProvider.getbydni(dni);
    buscarPaciente(context);
  }
  //se hace la peticion a la api del paciente 
  void submitPaciente(BuildContext context) async {
    patientModels = await patientProvider.buscarPaciente(dni);
    turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId =
        await turnPorivder.getAllByEmployeeId(userModel.employeeId);
    if (dni.isEmpty) {
      return utils.mostrarAlerta(context, "por favor ingrese un dni");
    }
    // _groupEvents(turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId);
    txtPaciente();
  }


   //se muestra un showdialog con la informacion del paciente y medico seleccionado 
  txtPaciente() {
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('El paciente buscado es'),
          content: Card(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Nombre: ${patientModels[0].firstName} - ${patientModels[0].lastName}',
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('DNI: ${patientModels[0].dni}'),
                ),
                Divider(),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Nombre del medico: ${turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId[0]['employee']['name']} - ${turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId[0]['employee']['lastName']}',
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Buscar de nuevo'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Turno'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop('Turno');
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ).then((value) => {
          if (value == 'Buscar de nuevo') {buscarPaciente(context)},
          if (value == 'Turno') {selecionarFecha()}
        });
  }

  //se muestra un DateTime para agendar el turno el dia que quiere el paciente
  selecionarFecha() async {
    DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: new DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: new DateTime(2222),
    );
    turnModel.userId = userModel.id;
    turnModel.employeeId = userModel.employeeId;
    turnModel.patientId = patientModels[0].id;
    turnModel.dateTime = picked;
    turnModel.state = 1;
    turnModel.isDeleted = false;

    if (picked != null) {
      turnPorivder.createTurn(turnModel);
    }
    // if (_events[_controller.selectedDay] != null) {
    //   _events[_controller.selectedDay]
    //       .add(turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId[0].dateTime);
    // } else {
    //   _events[_controller.selectedDay] = [''];
    // }
  }
}
```

turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId es una respuesta de la api adjunto foto de la respuesta que obtengo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: _events no veo que la llenes en algún momento, y de turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId  no veo de donde o como saques las fechas

Comment: turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId es la respuesta de una api que si tiene la fecha , intente llenar a _events con lo que tiene turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId pero la verdad no pude hacerlo no se como, ya intente googlear como convertir una lista a un map

Comment: Solo tienes que realizar un map, en tu listado que te regrese la fecha y el campo que ocupas mostrar de tu listado.

Comment: [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16831806) ```_events = Map.fromIterable(turnModelgetAllByEmployeeId, key: (v) => v['dateTime'], value: (v) => v['patient']['name']);```  [Map.fromIterable](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-core/Map/Map.fromIterable.html)

Comment: Hola Eduardo lo pude solucionar muchas gracias por darme una mano, no fue asi como lo solucione pero me guiaste a como hacerlo, reitero muchas gracias amigo, puedes ponerla como respuesta asi la voto como solucion?

Comment: mejor pon tu solución para ayudar a alguien mas que tenga un problema similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cree una funcion que recibe una lista dinamica, que la recorro completamente y agrego el DateTime que necesito, al final agrego el parametro que recibo

```
  Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> _gruopTurns(List<dynamic> turns) {
Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> data = {};
turns.forEach((element) {
  DateTime date = DateTime.tryParse(element['dateTime']);
  if (data[date] == null) data[date] = [];
  data[date].add(turns);
});
return data;
```